# What can I do with trainer levels?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know I can only use the gym feature after hitting level 5, but are there any other privilege or rewards for the levels above 5?

For example, in Ingress, some items are only available for the higher level player. How about Pokemon Go?

Comment: The rewards have been updated after the Gen 2 release. So the accepted answer to this question has to be updated.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5uo6ei/the_new_level_rewards/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are different rewards as you level up:

- As your level increases, so will the CP of wild Pokémon (which means you can capture stronger Pokémon) and you can find more species.
- Your level determines the CP cap for your Pokémon, so higher player levels mean that you can power up your Pokémon to higher CP.
- At level 5 you can start challenging gyms and participate in battles.
- At level 20, you receive Nanab Berries instead of Razz Berries. Then every odd level after 20 it will alternate between Nanab and Pinap Berries as a reward. [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5uo6ei/the_new_level_rewards/)
- Each level up grants item rewards, here is the list:

**Level 1:** (Starting Level)

**Level 2:** Poké Ball x10

**Level 3:** Poké Ball x15

**Level 4:** Poké Ball x15

**Level 5:** Poké Ball x20; Potion x10; Revive x10; Incense x1

**Level 6:** Poké Ball x15; Potion x10; Revive x5; Egg Incubator x1

**Level 7:** Poké Ball x15; Potion x10; Revive x5; Incense x1

**Level 8:** Poké Ball x15; Potion x10; Revive x5; Razz Berry x10;
 Lure Module x1

**Level 9:** Poké Ball x15; Potion x10; Revive x5; Razz Berry x3;
 Lucky Egg x1

**Level 10:** Poké Ball x20; Super Potion x20; Revive x10; Razz Berry x10; Incense x1; Lucky Egg x1; Egg Incubator x1; Lure Module x1

**Level 11:** Poké Ball x15; Super Potion x10; Revive x3; Razz Berry x3

**Level 12:** Great Ball x20; Super Potion x10; Revive x3; Razz Berry x 3

**Level 13:** Great Ball x10; Super Potion x10; Revive x3; Razz Berry x3

**Level 14:** Great Ball x10; Super Potion x10; Revive x3; Razz Berry x3

**Level 15:** Great Ball x15; Hyper Potion x20; Revive x10; Razz Berry x10; Incense x1; Lucky Egg x1; Egg Incubator x1; Lure Module x1

**Level 16:** Great Ball x10; Hyper Potion x10; Revive x5; Razz Berry x5

**Level 17:** Great Ball x10; Hyper Potion x10; Revive x5; Razz Berry x5

**Level 18:** Great Ball x10; Hyper Potion x10; Revive x5; Razz Berry x5

**Level 19:** Great Ball x15; Hyper Potion x10; Revive x5; Razz Berry x5

**Level 20:** Ultra Ball x20; Hyper Potion x20; Revive x20; Nanab Berry x20; Incense x2; Lucky Egg x2; Egg Incubator x2; Lure Module x2

**Level 21:** Ultra Ball x10; Hyper Potion x10; Revive x10; Pinap Berry x10

**Level 22:** Ultra Ball x10; Hyper Potion x10; Revive x10; Razz Berry x10

**Level 23:** Ultra Ball x10; Hyper Potion x10; Revive x10; Nanab Berry x10

**Level 24:** Ultra Ball x15; Hyper Potion x10; Revive x10; Razz Berry x10

**Level 25:** Ultra Ball x25; Max Potion x20; Revive x15; Pinap Berry x15; Incense x1; Lucky Egg x1; Egg Incubator x1; Lure Module x1

**Level 26:** Ultra Ball x10; Max Potion x15; Revive x10; Razz Berry x15

**Level 27:** Ultra Ball x10; Max Potion x15; Revive x10; Nanab Berry x15

**Level 28:** Ultra Ball x10; Max Potion x15; Revive x10; Razz Berry x15

**Level 29:** Ultra Ball x10; Max Potion x15; Revive x10; Pinap Berry x15

**Level 30:** Ultra Ball x30; Max Potion x20; Max Revive x20; Razz Berry x20; Incense x3; Lucky Egg x3; Egg Incubator x3; Lure Module x3

**Level 31:** Ultra Ball x10; Max Potion x15; Max Revive x10; Nanab Berry x15

**Level 32:** Ultra Ball x10; Max Potion x15; Max Revive x10; Razz Berry x15

**Level 33:** Ultra Ball x10; Max Potion x15; Max Revive x10; Pinap Berry x15

**Level 34:** Ultra Ball x10; Max Potion x15; Max Revive x10; Razz Berry x15

**Level 35:** Ultra Ball x30; Max Potion x20; Max Revive x20; Nanab Berry x20; Incense x2; Lucky Egg x1; Egg Incubator x1; Lure Module x1

**Level 36:** Ultra Ball x20; Max Potion x20; Max Revive x10; Razz Berry x20

**Level 37:** Ultra Ball x20; Max Potion x20; Max Revive x10; Pinap Berry x20

**Level 38:** Ultra Ball x20; Max Potion x20; Max Revive x10; Razz Berry x20

**Level 39:** Ultra Ball x20; Max Potion x20; Max Revive x10; Nanab Berry x20

**Level 40:** Ultra Ball x40; Max Potion x40; Max Revive x40; Razz Berry x40; Incense x4; Lucky Egg x4; Egg Incubator x4; Lure Module x4

**Level 40 is the maximum level**

My [source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Level_Rewards_and_Unlockable_Items) seems to be updated often (yesterday it only had reward info up to level 12)

Edit: Another [source](http://serebii.net/pokemongo/trainer.shtml)

Comment: To add to your list, I think at 15 it was when I first got Hyperpotions.

Comment: Might want to edit the first bullet point. Not only do the wild pokemon have the possibility of having a higher CP, also your pokemon can be trained to a higher CP. A pokemons CP cap is based off of your trainer level.

Comment: You get ultra balls at level 20. I am level 22. That's my source. @chalkos

Comment: @DavidJacobsen Thank you, I have edited the answer to include the CP cap.

Comment: @jdero That is correct :) And the source for the item rewards was updated, so I updated this list as well.

Comment: @Chalkos +1 for keeping it up to date!

Comment: @Kiwi thanks. the site is also being updated everyday. Masterball reward in 3, 2, 1... :D

Comment: Did someone update this table after the Gen 2 announcement? Because I did level up to L29 after it and received 15 Pinap berries along with other rewards on my level up so it seems that Niantic did change the rewards.

Answer (score 17):

Leveling up unlocks a very useful feature, **Pokestop Submission**. It was available only for level 40 players, but in late 2020 the required level was  lowered to level 38!

> Trainers who've reached level 38 can help grow the number of PokéStops in their community by nominating eligible objects and locations in Niantic Wayfarer.

Source, [Niantic Support](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=in-game-locations&f=submitting-a-pokestop-nomination&l=en&p=web).

---

You also have some in-game benefits.
As your level increases, you will discover more Pokémon and face Pokémon with stronger CP in the wild. You'll also get various perks and unlock new items.

Here's a nice table that summarizes the rewards through level 20:

[image]

#### UPDATE:

With [Go Beyond update](https://pokemongohub.net/post/guide/go-beyond-update/), level cap increased from the previous level 40 to level 50.

As well as meeting a certain threshold of XP, now you also need to complete certain challenges - named *Level Up Research* - in order to progress to the next level:

[image: level40-50 rewards]

You can find further info and relative rewards on [Serebii](http://serebii.net/pokemongo/trainer.shtml).

Answer (score 6):

- **Level 5:** you can join teams and get to do gym battles.
- **Level 6:** you can get a new type of Incubator with 3 uses, allowing us to incubate and hatch several eggs at the same time.
- **Level 8:** you can get razzberries, which make the next ball you throw have an increased chance of cathing the pokemon.

*I've not found any other information regarding leveling up, but I will update this as new information is presented.*

Comment: your... guessing?

Comment: As in why would you purchase Incubators after level 6 when you have you already have one with unlimited uses.

Comment: Regardless, we like fact-driven answers. -1 for being nothing more than users speculation

Comment: The answer given is not speculation. The speculation is on what the use of the Incubator is and how it works. I've corrected my answer to highlight that I was speculating on something surrounding the answer and not the answer itself.

Comment: I am level 6 now. Yeah I got a Incubator with 3 uses (the same one appeared in the shop). I still have the unlimited Incubator. Players can only install an incubator at the same time, so this item allows us to hatch two eggs in the same time.

Comment: @JayWong Great! I updated my answer.

Comment: @P1raten you're not able to get master balls at level 12

Answer (score 5):

Leveling up in Pokemon GO grants the player access to some new items depending on the level reached. In addition, Level 5 grants you the ability to battle at Gyms.

Leveling up also confers an item gift. It is also required in order to train stronger Pokemon, as a Pokemon's max CP is dependent upon the trainer's current level.

**Known Unlocks:**

Level 5: Potions and Revives
Level 8: Razz Berry
Level 10 (?): Super Potion
Level 12: Great Ball

Answer (score 5):

Level 5: – ability to Battle and claim gyms
              – Choosing your team
              – introduction to the new items potion       and revive that can now ne found at pokespots

Level 6: – Free Incubator alongside some other items

Level 7: – Free Lure Module alongside other items

Level 8: – introduction of a new item that can now be found at pokestops: Razz Berry

Level 9: – Free Lucky Egg alongside other items

Haven't leveled up more yet

Answer (score 3):

At level 12, I started getting Great Balls (about 20 as part of the level up to 12 bundle, and now frequently from stores). At some point - about level 10 or so - I also started getting Super Potions.

I know that besides items getting unlocked like this, level ties in to the maximum potential of your Pokemon. The two pokes I've been trying to keep maxed out - a Golduck and a Golbat - both gain more room to grow with each level. Honestly hope there's a max trainer level sometime soon as my other pokes are getting neglected while I keep these two at the top (stardust required to level gets higher and higher as you power up).

Answer (score 1):

At Level 38.5, you get the best possible Pokèmon in the community, as your Pokèmon will be Level 40. That is because that a Pokemon's Level is 1.5 more than the current trainers' Level. Source: [Another of my posts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303012/why-is-my-pok%C3%A9mon-not-at-its-max-potential-cp)

Answer (score 0):

At 20 you get Ultra Balls by the way, and at 25 you get Max Potions

Comment: This is more of a comment than a full fledged answer.

Answer (score -1):

Something the others haven't mentioned yet: when you reach level 15, you'll get Hyper Potion. It heals 200 HP of a Pokemon when used.