# Great Ball at PokeStops

Tags: pokemon-go

At level 12 [From This Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272594/what-can-i-do-with-trainer-levels) you start to obtain great balls when leveling.

I am currently level 6 and have only ever gotten normal pokeballs from pokestops.

Is there at any point (possibly after 12) where pokestops start giving better balls?

Comment: What's the question? AFAIKT you've already answered.

Comment: @OrangeDog I think he meant acquiring better pokeballs apart from leveling. Like from pokestops.

Comment: @OrangeDog better than great ball. He's wanting to know when greater balls are unlocked.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I am level 12 and once you "unlock" the great ball it will be dropped at pokestops. They are harder to get than normal pokeballs. This goes for nearly every item (eg. razzberries, super potions, etc).

Answer (score 11):

All items that will be given at pokéstops require you to unlock them first.

After you reach the required level then you will start to receive them as well.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you receive Ultra Balls at level 20.
Note that once you unlock an item, it becomes obtainable at PokeStops.

Source: http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Level_Rewards_and_Unlockable_Items

Comment: halpful, but asker is not asking about ultra balls

Comment: @Timelord64 he asks for "better balls", so unless ultra balls are not *better* than the normal pokeballs (which they are as a matter of fact), Pyritie actually did answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! We unlock a Pokemon Go [great ball](http://www.letspokemongo.com/get-great-ball-ultra-ball-master-ball-pokemon-go/) at level 12 and an ultra ball at level 20. But I'm really surprised that everyone forgot Master Ball! I was expecting master ball as well in Pokemon Go!

Answer (score 0):

ultra balls come after level 20. Max revive as well.