# Can you receive Incubators from Pokestops?

Tags: pokemon-go

Since hatching eggs is such a big part of progressing in Pokemon Go, and you only have one infinite use incubator... this means incubators are a pretty useful commodity. Can you ever receive them from Pokestops? And if so, what level do you need to be?

Comment: I have not heard of this happening to anybody, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Well, like several other items in the game you might need to be a higher level to 'unlock' them at pokestops. I can't find this information anywhere yet.

Comment: I imagine you need to be at least level 6, you can't get any other incubators before that... but i don't have enough to make a full answer.

Comment: While not a pokestop, you can receive an incubator as a level-up bonus for specific levels.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272594/what-can-i-do-with-trainer-levels

Answer (score 15):

I don't believe that you can receive Lures, Incubators, Lucky Eggs, or Incense from Pokéstops, and that you must either purchase them from the store or receive them as a reward for leveling up. I don't have any evidence other than anecdotal at level 20 with 1000+ visited Pokéstops. If anyone has any counter-evidence please post it!

Comment: I don't have any screenshots of it but I did get an Incubator with 3 uses from a pokestop once.

Comment: I have found an incubator with 3 uses around level 6. Unfortunately I cannot remember how I have acquired it but it is definitely not bought from the shop.

Comment: @YunusNedimMehel You got that as a gift for reaching level 6.

Comment: Are you sure those weren't from leveling up?

Comment: @Taegost: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/273507/68492

Comment: I deleted my comment, I'm actually not certain they weren't from leveling up.  I was thinking back on it yesterday and there were a couple times that I leveled up, but the level up didn't happen until 20-30 minutes after it actually happened, and I think some of the rewards got reported on my screen as coming from the Poke Stop, but didn't show up in my journal when I looked it up after this discussion

Comment: Incubators are now (and have been for a while) acquirable via research rewards.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.gamesradar.com/pokemon-go-level-rewards/

You get 1 incubator at level 6, 10, 15 and 2 incubators at level 20.

Comment: According to http://www.thesilphroad.com/ you also get another 1 at 25, 3 at 30, and 4 at 40.

Answer (score 2):

Items from the Shop (with the sole exception of Pokeballs) may not be acquired without the use of Pokecoins or the level-up bonus.

This is an intended feature of Niantic's -- these items are "premium," and therefore, are to be bought in order to generate a revenue supply from the game.

Answer (score -1):

You can get incubators from pokestops. I received one (with three uses) a couple of days ago around level 4 or 5. Unfortunately, I didn't realize it was apparently a rare event or I would have taken a screenshot. It also has fallen off my journal or I'd screenshot that. They are out there!

The incubator is on its last use now so I was trying to check how rare they are from pokestops when I found this question.

Edit: I see now that you apparently get one from leveling up to 6. I was pretty sure I had it before then, but perhaps not. I don't have two, so if you 100% get one from leveling to 6 then it must be that one. Leaving this post for posterity anyway cause why not.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can get incubators from Pokéstops. All the incubators I got were from Pokéstops. I didn't spend any money on them. I had a lot of luck I guess, because my brothers and cousin didn't get any of them.

Answer (score -2):

Can't say for sure, but [this page](http://www.ibtimes.com/what-can-you-get-pokestops-how-obtain-incubators-incense-lure-modules-more-pokemon-go-2392378) from "International Business Times" says you can obtain Incubators from Pokéstops.

Comment: I'd like to understand why am I being downvoted. I just posted a link to a website that says it is possible to receive incubators from pokéstops, making it clear I don't know this for sure. Do you have any evidence that says this is wrong? I don't see any evidence in any other answer here. But I'd be glad to know if this is wrong.

Answer (score -3):

I have 2 of the 3-use incubators, I'm level 11, never spent a cent in the shop, after checking the level rewards, I'm pretty sure I got one from pokestop.[image]

Comment: I can't remember what level they're given at, but you get given an incubator for leveling up twice pre 15

Comment: You should really use your 3-use incubators for the 10K's, not your infinite incubator.  The reason being, because they're so rare, you want to get the most you can out of each incubator use, in terms of KM.  Use your infinite on 2's until there are none left, and only then on 5's :D

Comment: You get them at levels 6 and 10, that's why you had 2.

Comment: "You should really use your 3-use incubators for the 10K's, not your infinite incubator." Sigh. The disposable and infinity incubators work identically, so which one you put which eggs in can't make a difference. Mathematically, the best strategy is to to always incubate the shortest egg you have in your stash -- even without taking evolution experience into account (when you count evolution experience, 2K eggs are worth more than 3000 experience).

Comment: above should be "five 2K eggs are worth more than 3000 experience". That's actually really low, it's more like 4000 or more. Whereas one 10K egg is worth somewhere around 1500 experience.

Answer (score -4):

soo a friend of mine have 3 incubators and she says that she got them frome pokestops and i belive here she is only lv 7 so yes i think u can get it frome pokestops but its has a low drop rate ^-^

Comment: She totally bought them.

Comment: Or she received it by levelling up to level 6