# Why haven't I received more Lucky Eggs since level 12?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am currently on level 17, and since level 12 I've not received a single Lucky Egg.

Are Lucky Eggs difficult to obtain after level 12 or 15? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: I think it's just bad luck

Comment: Firstly, where are you expecting to get lucky eggs from? Secondly, you might be confusing yourself, because you only get a lucky egg when you hit level 9, 10, 15, and 20 (and select levels after that). Level 12 only rewards you with items you can get from a poketsop.

Comment: @Ben - That's the answer: There's set rewards per-level, if rahul wants more Lucky Eggs before level 20, he'll have to buy them. :-)

Comment: Duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272594/86987?

Comment: @MartinEnder How is this question a duplicate? The question is entirely different.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok The accepted answer of this question doesn't contain any information that can't be found in the accepted answer of the question I linked as far as I can tell. So whether the specific question asked is different or not, the OP's question was already answered in the previous thread. Whether that qualifies as a duplicate by Arqade's policies I can't say, but it would on some other SEs (but that's why there 's a "?" at the end of my comment).

Comment: Just because the answer to a completely different question happens to contain the information to answer this question, that's not the definition of a "duplicate **question**".  The correct way to link to the other question is "You can find the answers here, in this completely unrelated question."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In conjunction with [luser droog's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/278479/73976), to answer your question in regards to levelling, you receive a Lucky Egg (along with other rewards) when you hit levels:

- **9:** 15 Poké Balls, 10 Potions, 5 Revives, 3 Razz Berries, **1 Lucky Egg**
- **10:** 15 Poké Balls, 10 Super Potions, 10 Revives, 10 Razz Berries, 1 Incense, **1 Lucky Egg**, 1 Egg Incubator, 1 Lure Module
- **15:** 15 Poké Balls, 10 Super Potions, 10 Revives, 10 Razz Berries, 1 Incense, **1 Lucky Egg**, 1 Egg Incubator, 1 Lure Module
- **20:** 20 Ultra Balls, 20 Hyper Potions, 20 Revives, 20 Razz Berry, 2 Incense, **2 Lucky Eggs**, 2 Egg Incubators, 2 Lure Modules
- **25:** 25 Ultra Balls, 20 Max Potions, 15 Revives, 15 Razz Berries, 1 Incense, **1 Lucky Egg**, 1 Egg Incubator, 1 Lure Module
- **30:** 30 Ultra Balls, 20 Max Potions, 20 Max Revives, 20 Razz Berries, 3 Incense, **3 Lucky Eggs**, 3 Egg Incubators, 3 Lure Modules

[Source](http://www.polygon.com/2016/7/19/12227650/pokemon-go-level-rewards)

You may get some at higher levels, but I'm not sure when (or even if you can surpass level 30).

As luser droog suggested however, if you want more eggs more frequently, you're better off cashing in on the defender bonus to buy them, or paying for micro transactions, depending on how desperate you are.

Comment: Level 40 is the current maximum.

Answer (score 8):

Get in some gyms and buy one!

Seriously though. If you can't hold on to a gym then just cash out right away. 1 gym X 8 days = 80 coins == 1 lucky egg.

If you *can* hold a gym for a while, then hit a few on your poke-walk and cash-out when you get home.

Comment: i already have 30 so i need to have 50 more, thats nice thanks for idea